# Botão aparecer somente após vê todos os slides do carrossel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo uma interação que a pessoa só pode avançar quando vê todos os slides de um carrossel, mas meu código só funciona quando a pessoa clica em 1 indicador do carrossel e não em todos. Estou usando o carrossel do Bootstrap. Vou colocar o meu código.

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>

<script>
 $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').on('click',function(){
    $('.btn').css('display','block');
    $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').off('click');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Então a pergunta está errada! Vc quer que o usuário veja o último slide e não todos.

Comment: Foi mal, cliquei sem querer como resposta correta, to na correria aqui, mas o seu código é o correto, foi mal msm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione uma classe específica ao slide já visto (por exemplo, `.visto`) e que não confunda com outra classe usada na página. A classe `.visto` será usada apenas nos indicadores. Quando você chamar o evento `click` você adiciona essa classe no indicador e compara se o número de classes `.visto` existentes é igual ao número de elementos com o atributo `[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]`. Se for igual, você mostra o botão.

Mas antes é preciso adicionar essa classe no slide ativo inicialmente ao carregar a página:

```js
$(function(){ // aguarda o carregamento do DOM
   $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"].active').addClass('visto'); // adiciona a classe no indicador ativo
   var slides = $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').length; // conta o número de slides
   
   $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').on('click',function(){
      $(this).addClass('visto'); // adiciona a classe .visto no indicador clicado
      if(slides == $('.visto').length){ // faz a comparação
         $('.btn').show(); // mostra o botão
         $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').off('click'); // remove a escuta do evento
      }
   });
});
```

```css
#carouselExampleIndicators{
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.btn{
   display: none;
}
</style>
<button class="btn">Continuar</button>
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Observação:** isso só irá funcionar se a pessoa clicar nos indicadores, como indicado explicitamente na pergunta. Mas lembre-se
>   que o carousel pode ficar rodando automaticamente ou pode ter setas de
>   navegação "esquerda/direita". Se a intenção é mostrar o botão também
>   nesses casos, teria que reformular o código.

Answer (score 2):

Imagino que você está querendo algo assim:

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').on('click',function(e) {
       var total_slide = $('[data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators"]').length;

       if (total_slide == ($(this).index() + 1)) {
          $('.btn').css('display','block');
       } else {
          e.preventDefault();
          $(this).off('click');
       }
   });
});
</script>
```